# Unit testing assert that json response contains a list

Tags: unit-testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

When writing a unit test in phoenix framework how do you check if a json response contains a list.

Existing test is below which fails because `children` gets populated. I just want the test to tell me that my json response contains `children` and `children` is a list.

```
test "shows chosen resource", %{conn: conn} do
  parent = Repo.insert! %Parent{}
  conn = get conn, parent_path(conn, :show, parent)
  assert json_response(conn, 200)["data"] == %{"id" => parent.id,
    "children" => []}
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use three asserts for this, using a pattern match assert first to assert the basic structure and extract `id` and `children`:

```
assert %{"id" => id, "children" => children} = json_response(conn, 200)["data"]
assert id == parent.id
assert is_list(children)
```

Note that this test will pass even if the map contains keys other than `id` and `children`.

Answer (score 2):

With [json schema][2] you can generate a json to use with (https://github.com/jonasschmidt/ex_json_schema) to validate a full json structure.

```
iex> schema = %{
  "type" => "object",
  "properties" => %{
    "foo" => %{
      "type" => "string"
    }
  }
} |> ExJsonSchema.Schema.resolve
```

and

```
 iex> ExJsonSchema.Validator.valid?(schema, %{"foo" => "bar"})
```

and remember *have only one logical assertion per test*” (http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/08/24/writing-great-unit-tests-best-and-worst-practises/)